# exit the batch file after running using java

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I know how to start the batch file using java code.
When i run the batch file command prompt is opened.
To close the command prompt i am using the taskill /im cmd.exe.
but the problem is that the command prompt that is used to start the jboss is also closed.
i want to kill the cmd with a particular process id.
How do i get the process id of a particular cmd promt and kill that using java

Comment: I would register JBoss as a service instead.  For example, see this script I wrote:  https://gist.github.com/djangofan/5639409

Answer (score 3):

Run the batch file with `cmd.exe /c job.bat`. The `/c` switch carries out the command and then terminates the command interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

can't you add `exit` to your batch file to exit it's own command prompt. Uisng taskill seems overkill for just closing one command prompt, don't you think?

PS: I've never worked on batch files just the command prompt so I'm assuming it accepts the same commands.

Comment: ur idea is good.
but the problem is that i want to close it after 15 minutes. if i give exit in the batch file then it will close immediately.

Comment: zach's answer doesn't wait for 15 minutes either!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that works: to close command window after executing the commands from the batch (.bat) file you need to add "exit" (without the quotes) in a new line of your batch file. If you want to delay the execution this is the way and it works:

```
public class TestSleep 
{
    public static void main ( String [ ] args ) 
    {
         System.out.println("Do this stuff");
         try 
         { 
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000); 
         }
         catch ( Exception e ) { }
         System.out.println("Now do everything after this");
     } 
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you start the batch file with Runtime.exec(), it returns you a Process object. Calling the destroy() method will kill that process.

Comment: @abc: You must combine this tip with the "cmd /c".

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. I first used as

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe start /c test.bat");
```

Then I tried as below. It works fine.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start test.bat");
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Although this seems to be an old question and probably resolved.. I struggled with the same thing for a long time.. Finally this works

```
String command = "cmd.exe /c build.bat";
Runtime rt = Runtime().getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(command);
```